# references bower packages in angular component

Tags: angular

My project contains many bower packages in bower_components dir. I want to use bower package in angular component. How to do it?
[image]

import styles.less in app-header.component.less

[image]

error:
[image]

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: error: .clearfix() is undefined. .clearfix() defined in l3/styles.less, I don't know how to import it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import using full path from the `bower_components` like this -

```
@import "~3l/3L/styles.less";
```

Comment: I can't import it.

Comment: what's the meaning of ~

Comment: Try this `@import url("3l/3L/styles.less");`

Comment: I have already solved. `@import "../../bower_components/3l/styles";`